# codes i want to change from "php" to "Javascript"

Tags: php

this is the **PHP** code

```
<?php
if (file_get_contents('http://www.anysite.com/anypath/anyfile.php')=="anydata") {
echo "OK";}
ELSE {
ECHO "Not OK";}
?>
```

i want to change this from "**php**" to "**javascript**" i tried to do it but no results , because "file_get_contents" function , 
so any help please ?!

Comment: This is not a translation service

Comment: @PeterM i just asked for help !

Comment: you can't use file_get_contents in javascript. It's a client side script

Comment: @bksi so any other options ?

Comment: You should describe what you want to do, not to translate

Comment: In what context? @bski JS can be both, see: [node](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: No. You can use ajax, to check if this file is present on the server, but i'm not sure what exacly you want from this.

Comment: Emissary, from tags of this question i don't see node, so i assume that Mohhamed wants to use it in the browser.

Comment: @bksi like use location.herf in get >> to know were the script is being used ..

Comment: so you can use ajax, to check this location, and from response you can dynamicly change the html

Comment: @bksi the only tag I see is PHP which suggests server-side - so that's a straw man answer, I merely pointed it out because your comment states categorically *"it's a client side script"* which isn't strictly true.

Comment: @bksi any other way ?

Comment: nope. you have to make a call to the server to see if the file exists there. Other way is with PHP

Answer (score 1):

with jquery you can use this function

```
function urlExists(url, callback){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: url,
    success: function(){
      callback(true);
    },
    error: function() {
      callback(false);
    }
  });
}
```

and in js use it with:

```
var exists = urlExists(url);
if (exists) { 
   // do your staff here 
}
```

Comment: about the other way "urlExists" can i use urlExists('http://site.com/get.php?link='+escape(location.href)); - and send it to the get.php file ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense

Comment: You want to make a crawler or what?

Comment: in urlExists it just check of the file exist or server exist or what?

Comment: Yes. This checks if the file exists on the server. If it doesn't the server returns 404

Comment: i want to make a js file the send to me the location.herf

Comment: so if i a put "get Request " it will be sent  ?!

Comment: to my site for example !

Comment: You can't use client js to send requests to other servers. You can get the request directly from PHP. I don't see need to use js for this.

Comment: Lol iam already done it -"a=new/**/Image();a.src='http://site.com/get.php?get='+escape(location.href);" - but in "file_get_contents" u can check if the request success or not , for that i need another way to send it , i can't use PHP because the script is already with to many people and i have ".js" file in my site that in the "script file" - usung src - and i will edit it and put this code

Comment: You can use directly img url to check if the img exists

Answer (score 0):

FILE_GET_CONTENTS doesn't really have an analog in JS since it's a client-side scripting language. You could use location.href='http://www.anysite.com/anypath/anyfile.php'; to force a download file dialog box but this is probably not what you're looking to accomplish. Why does it need to be in JavaScript anyways?